# Compiler Bug when using ?. resulting in a Bad Image that fails PEVerify

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

I stumbled across something odd: I got a `BadImageFormatException` without knowing what image (assembly) it could possibly refer to.

I reduced the solution so that it consists only of a single project with no dependencies:

[image]

As you can see, it only uses `System` (and `mscorlib`), and of course I don't load assemblies at run time.

It compiles as AnyCpu with .NET 4.5.2, VS 2015 with C#6, although none of this should really matter.

I tried to make a sample with C#5, but once I replace all the "?." operators, it stops happening.

I have hosted the project so that people can try it themselves:

```
git clone -b crash-sample https://github.com/jtheisen/moldinium.git
```

I clean-built and tested it on 4 machines, all showing the same effect.

The stack trace of the crash is:

```
Ex.: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at IronStone.Moldinium.LiveList.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<Where>b__2(ListEvent`1 v)
   at IronStone.Moldinium.ActionObserver`1.OnNext(T value) in C:\Source\Repos\moldinium\ConsoleApplication1\Rx.cs:line 51
...snipped...
```

Running PEVerify on the output produces the following error:

> [IL]: Error:
>   [C:\Source\Repos\moldinium\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\Bad.exe :
>   IronStone.Moldinium.LiveList+<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1[TSource]::b__2][offset
>   0x0000013B] Unable to resolve token.

Removing all the `?.` operators from the Select.cs file resolves the issue.

Using ILSpy I have isolated the problem to:

```
IronStone.Moldinium.LiveList.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<Where>b__2
```

You can see the IL Dumps of the method (via ILSpy) in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/xdaDaveShaw/06276472f45f8f5126193aeaf4233d7a). The Bad IL is when using `?.` the Good IL is C# 5.0 style.

This has been build with VS2015.3

> CSC Version: Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 1.3.1.60616

Comment: @DaveShaw Looks like I'm lucky to have found you. I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: I've re-written the question and incorporated my comments to be more about the Compiler bug and less about the runtime crash.

Comment: You may want to post this on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I was wondering if someone would narrow it down, but I've posted an issue anyway: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12439

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you because it's indeed a bug. But I can take you to the point where the bug occur and it may help you to reproduce the bug in a few lines of code.

```
namespace ElvisBugInNullableGenericStructWithNestedTypeParameter
{
    struct MyGenericStruct<T> { }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main() { }

        void Test<T>()
        {
            Func<T, bool> func = (arg =>
                {
                    MyGenericStruct<T>? v1 = null;
                    return v1?.ToString() == null;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

If I will replace `MyGenericStruct<T>?` with `MyGenericStruct<int>?` it will work.

The problem is that, from some reason, when we use the outer `T` in nullable struct and then we try to use the Elvis operator `?` the type is unknown (unable to resolve token).

**Update**
If you want to fix your case, you don't need to remove all Elvis operator, just remove them from `Subscribe` action within `public static ILiveList<TSource> Where<TSource>(this ILiveList<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Boolean> predicate)` method.